# How can I make this query to detect multiple accounts more efficient & play well w/ has_many?

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance

In my User model, I want to search for whether a user has multiple accounts (aka 'multis').

Users have sessions; sessions are customized to set

1. `creator_id` = ID of first user the session was logged in as, and
2. `updater_id` = ID of last user the session was logged in as

(Both columns are indexed.)

If I detect that the two are different when a session is saved, I save the session for posterity (and this query), because it means that the user logged in as one and then logged in as the other - aka they're a multi. (To catch the recursive base case, the `creator_id` is then reset on the current session.)

Here's the code that does it:

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session
  attr_accessor :skip_setters

  before_save :set_ip
  before_save :set_user

    def set_user
      return true if self.skip_setters
      # First user on this session
      self.creator_id ||= self.data[:user_id] 
      # Last user on this session
      self.updater_id = self.data[:user_id] if self.data[:user_id] 
      if self.creator_id and self.updater_id and 
       self.creator_id != self.updater_id
        logger.error "MULTI LOGIN: User #{self.creator.login} and \
          #{self.updater.login} from #{self.ip}"

        # Save a copy for later inspection
        backup = Session.new {|dup_session| 
          dup_session.attributes = self.attributes
          # overwrite the session_id so we don't conflict with the 
          # current one & it can't be used to log in
          dup_session.session_id = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(16)
          dup_session.skip_setters = true
        }
        backup.save

        # Set this session to be single user again.
        # Updater is what the user looks for;
        # creator is the one that's there to trigger this.
        self.creator_id = self.updater_id
      end
    end

  # etc... e.g. log IP
end
```

The following query does work.

However, it's ugly, not very efficient, and doesn't play well with Rails' association methods. Keep in mind that sessions is an extremely large and heavily used table, and users almost as much.

I'd like to change this into a has_many association (so that all the associational magic works); possibly `:through =>` a `:multi_sessions` association. It should capture both directions of multihood, not just one like the current association.

How can this be improved?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :sessions, :foreign_key => 'updater_id'

 # This association is only unidirectional; it won't catch the reverse case
 # (i.e. someone logged in first as this user and then as the other)
 has_many :multi_sessions, :foreign_key => 'updater_id', 
  :conditions => 'sessions.updater_id != sessions.creator_id',
  :class_name => 'Session'
 has_many :multi_users, :through => :multi_sessions,
  :source => 'creator', :class_name => 'User'

 ...

 # This does catch both, but is pretty ugly :(
 def multis
  # Version 1
  User.find_by_sql "SELECT DISTINCT users.* FROM users \
    INNER JOIN sessions \
      ON (sessions.updater_id = #{self.id} XOR sessions.creator_id = {self.id}) AND \
         (sessions.updater_id = users.id XOR sessions.creator_id = users.id) \
    WHERE users.id !=  #{self.id}"
  # Version 2
  User.find(sessions.find(:all, :conditions => 'creator_id != updater_id', 
    :select => 'DISTINCT creator_id, updater_id').map{|x|
      [x.creator_id, x.updater_id]}.flatten.uniq - [self.id])
 end
end
```

Comment: Why do you let a session change user ID during its course?  Assuming there is a good reason for doing so (a reason which eludes me right now), why don't you simply track that a session changes user ID when it changes?  Doing it retroactively seems to complicate life unnecessarily - and your query is slow and unreliable.

Comment: For example, I may want to persist flash messages across a login/logout; this requires a persistent session. (Or alternately, persisting part of the data across two "different" sessions, which really isn't much gain.)

Doing it retroactively means that I can go look at the session data later (eg if there was some abuse going on), know the relative timing, etc. I.e., auditing purposes.

Plus - I *do* track that it changes ID when it changes; that's what the after_save trap is for. :-P

Comment: OK: so make the 'after_save' trap record that the change occurred so that you don't have to grope around the DBMS for the information; record what you need when it happens.  I'll take your word that the persistent flash is correct - it sounds mostly plausible, but it isn't my area of expertise.

Comment: If your code works, see http://refactormycode.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're trying to solve of session re-use is a strange one.  You're much better off mapping IPs to unique logins by processing your logs to detect sock-puppets or users with multiple accounts.  There are more reliable and easier ways to solve your problem.